# how to call a function to run on different data sets determined by user input in python?

Tags: python, function, user-input

I have routes (`route001` and `route002`). The user will select either one. I then need the code to recognise what route has been selected and change the `start` and `directions` variables accordingly (in the code below `start` and `directions` has the data for `route001`). I then want to run the function called `vectors()` on the route data that was selected.

I am unsure of how to change `start` and `directions` depending on what route the user selected.
I am also unsure how to call the function `vectors()` on the route data. I am not confident either that I have created the function correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated as I am very new to this.

```
  route001 = (3, 12, 'S', 'S', 'W', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'S', 'W',
            'W', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'W', 'N', 'N',
            'E', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'S', 'S', 'W', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S',
            'S', 'E', 'N', 'E', 'E')

  route002 = (12, 11, 'W', 'W', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'W', 'W', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'W', 'W', 
        'W', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'N', 'N', 
        'W', 'W', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'S')

  start = [route001[0]] + [route001[1]]
  directions = route001[2:]

  coordinates = {"N": [0, 1], 'E': [1, 0], 'S': [0, -1], 'W': [-1, 0]}


  def vectors():

  for d in directions:
    dx, dy = coordinates[d]
    start[0] += dx
    start[1] += dy
    if start[0] < 0 or start[0] > 12:
        print('Error: This route goes outside the grid')
        break
    elif start[1] < 0 or start[1] > 12:
        print('Error: This route goes outside the grid')
        break
    else:
        print(start)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let the user input 1 or 2:

```
routeSelection = input("Press 1 or 2 to select a route")
```

Then asign `start` and `directions` accordingly:

```
if routeSelection == "1":
    selectedRoute = route001
else if routeSelection == "2":
    selectedRoute = route002
else #error

start = [selectedRoute [0]] + [selectedRoute [1]]
directions = selectedRoute [2:]
```

---

To then call the `vectors` function just put

```
vectors()
```

(Since the vector function uses the global `start` and `directions`, you dont need to pass any argument.)

OR:

You could also define the `vectors()` to take arguments and then call it by passing `start` and `directions` as arguments. To avoid confusion, you might want to rename the parameters inside the `vectors` function to something else:

```
# call of vectors
vectors(start, directions)

def vectors(startPoint, directionsList):
  for d in directionsList:
    dx, dy = coordinates[d]
    startPoint[0] += dx
    startPoint[1] += dy
    ...
```

If you decide to go this way AND you dont need the `start` and `directions` variable in the global scope, you could even directly call `vectors()` with the according arguments without assigning `start` and `directions` at all:

```
vectors([selectedRoute [0]] + [selectedRoute [1]], selectedRoute [2:])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice, it first produced the error but when I put the 1 or 2 within "" it worked.

Comment: so at this stage i have selected for instance route 1, start and directions has the correct variables contained within them. How do i configure the vector function to run on the selected data?

Comment: Ah vectors(). this is the best most frustrating thing i have ever done lol

Comment: Thats just what happens while programming ;)

Comment: your advice has been gold. so thank you for taking the time to answer. Can you explain what you mean by renaming them to avoid confusion?

Comment: renaming woud just make sense if you want to use local parametes inside `vectors()` and passing them as arguments. In that case you could have different naming inside the function to make clear which variable is local and which is global. (Ill edit the answer)